# MySQL GROUP BY "and filter"

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Let's say i have query like this:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(number)
FROM objects
GROUP BY name
```

And it outputs:

```
+----------+----------------------+
|  NAME    | GROUP_CONCAT(NUMBER) |
+----------+----------------------+
| false_1  | 2,1                  |
| false_2  | 3,4                  |
| true_1   | 4,3,2,1              |
| true_2   | 2,3                  |
+----------+----------------------+
```

Now how can i return rows having `2 AND 3` as `number`?

**Note:** This query is grouped - table has 10 rows, like so:

```
+---------+--------+
|  NAME   | NUMBER |
+---------+--------+
| true_1  | 1      |
| true_1  | 2      |
| true_1  | 3      |
| ...     | ...    |
+---------+--------+
```

[[Link to SQLFiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faae0/5)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(number)
FROM objects
WHERE number IN (2,3)
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SEE SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faae0/9)

or if you want to retain all value on which the name has,

```
SELECT  a.name, GROUP_CONCAT(A.number)
FROM    objects a
        INNER JOIN
        (
          SELECT name
          FROM objects
          WHERE number IN (2,3)
          GROUP BY name
          HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
        ) b ON a.Name = b.Name
GROUP BY a.name
```

- [SEE SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faae0/32)

Comment: Why the row `true_1   | 4,3,2,1  ` isn't returned in its form.

Comment: Another question, but how can i cpunt there rows?
[With subquery](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faae0/61)?
Or is there any better solution?

Comment: @Kristian [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fa8c/1) although i'm not sure with this, i'll better go for subquery.